# How to calculate time difference between two H:M:S character strings in R?

Tags: r

I have two character strings that describe time of day.

```
session_start <- "9:31:56"
session_end <- "10:57:25"
```

I essentially want to subtract `session_start` from `session_end` to get the time difference (or time elapsed to put it another way). How can I do that?

I'd finally like to convert the result of `session_end - session_start` from an H:M:S output to only total minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a <- diff(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), c(session_start, session_end))))
as.numeric(a, units = 'mins')

[1] 85.48333
```

---

using `data.table`:

```
(b <- diff(data.table::as.ITime(c(session_start,session_end))))
[1] "01:25:29"
```

To convert this to minutes use:

```
as.numeric(structure(b, class='difftime', units='secs'), units='mins')
[1] 85.48333
```

---

Using basic math:

```
d <- read.table(text=c(session_start,session_end), sep = ':')
diff(c(c(60, 1, 1/60) %*% t(d)))
[1] 85.48333
```

---

If you have a dataframe with two columns, use the following:
Using the `df` from the solution by @allan we can do:

```
a <- with(df, 
         as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), ends)) - 
         as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), starts))) |>
    as.numeric(units='mins')

ifelse(a > 0, a, 1440 + a)
[1]  86.31667 276.85000
```

Note that this is

Answer (score 2):

Using `strptime` then `difftime`.

```
> difftime(strptime(session_end, "%T"), strptime(session_start, "%T"), unit='mins')
Time difference of 85.48333 mins
```

If you want numerics, do e.g.

```
> as.numeric(difftime(strptime(session_end, "%T"), strptime(session_start, "%T"), 
+                     units='secs'))
[1] 5129
```

---

*Data:*

```
session_start <- "9:31:56"
session_end <- "10:57:25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Often we will need vectorized output in R, so that we can pass a whole column of start times and a whole column of finish times. The following function does that, and additionally handles edge cases where the finish time is after midnight and therefore "wraps around" to the next day. For completeness, it also outputs in the H:M:S format to show the time difference in easy-to-understand format.

```r
time_diff <- function(starts, ends) {
  a <- sapply(strsplit(starts, ":"), \(s) sum(as.numeric(s) * c(3600, 60, 1)))
  b <- sapply(strsplit(ends, ":"), \(s) sum(as.numeric(s) * c(3600, 60, 1)))
  b[b < a] <- b[b < a] + 86400
  substr(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + b - a, 12, 19)
}
```

Testing on your own example, we have:

```r
session_start <- "9:31:56"
session_end   <- "10:57:25"

time_diff(session_start, session_end)
#> [1] "01:25:29"
```

And in a typical data analytic context:

```r
df <- data.frame(starts = c("13:54:51", "23:08:09"), 
                 ends = c("15:21:10", "03:45:00"))

df %>%
  mutate(session_length = time_diff(starts, ends))
#>     starts     ends session_length
#> 1 13:54:51 15:21:10       01:26:19
#> 2 23:08:09 03:45:00       04:36:51
```